# Jade variable from array // not working

Tags: arrays, express, pug

I'm passing an array to the jade document. Then I'd like to access the values of the array via a variable to keep the markup simple. Just see the example below. I have already picked up, that the jade syntax can be quite strange dealing with arrays (stuff like "arr.[0]"). Can you guys tell me what im overseeing here? Big thanks!

```
- var arr = [
        {
            name: 'foo',
            id: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'bar',
            id: 2
        }
    ]

- var item = arr[0];

h2 #{item.id} // doesn't work
h2 #{arr[0].id} // works
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h2 #{arr[0].id}
```

Works because you are referencing the id for arr item in the '0' (first) position.  This is because the array starts counting things with a zero, not a one.
As you can probably see from your results, this code would return '1', which means that you could expect `h2 #{arr[0].name}` To return 'foo'.

To get the ids from both items in the array 'arr', change your code to this.

```
h2 #{arr[0].id}
h2 #{arr[1].id}
```

Comment: Also it looks like Jade assignments don't need a semicolon.  var item = arr[0]

Comment: Thats not my quesiton, sry. I know how to address different entries in arrays in general. But here I'd like to connect the item-var to the spot in the array.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.